# com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, deployment, oauth-2.0

I have been stuck at "Deploy to APP Engine" from Eclipse, and following error message always popped up. Possible actions what I can think of were taken but all failed.

```
An error occurred while retrieving projects: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Bad Request"
}
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Bad Request"
}
```

Here is my situation what I have right now.

1. Application(Java Servlet) run normally in debug level
2. "Deploy to App Engine" from Eclipse was working fine in 2018 around
3. Available software have been up to date
4. I followed instruction of Java 8 Deploy manual (Google), and re-init the project and authenticated my account successfully
   https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/building-app/environment-setup?hl=ja

Does anyone help me to solve this problem? I want to deploy my application to the Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: It seems a similar concern was addressed in this [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166229/error-while-deploying-to-appengine-with-eclipse), the user seems to have resolved the issue by signing out and back into the Google Plugin for Eclipse as the OAuth tokens may have expired

Comment: Thank you very much for fixing my problem! I spent more than 2 days for fixing this problem. You are my hero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cloud resolve this problem by signing out and back into the Google Plugin for Eclipse. The OAuth tokens had been expired since I kept logged in my google account in 2018.